# What is the word for either reading or listening to books?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I ask someone whether they have read a certain book, they often reply with something along the lines of: "Yes. Well, actually I listened to the audio book". Or vice versa.

What is the verb that I could use that would

1. cover the meaning of either reading or listening to the book and
2. make sense to the vast majority of people?

The word would fit in to the following blank:

> Have you ____ *Mastery* by Robert Greene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few you could use, although they are not as common as the specific one for the medium in question—and they're more often used when you already know that somebody has started something.

> Have you **finished** *Mastery* by Robert Greene?
>   Have you **consumed** *Mastery* by Robert Greene?

The latter is using the Merriam-Webster's sense of [**consumed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consume) that means "to enjoy avidly," as in "mysteries, which she consumes for fun."

And, given that, you could also simply ask if they've **enjoyed** the book—although that seems a bit odd if you're not after a "review."

---

It might be strange to use either of those verbs without context, however. If you're asking somebody in general, even if you know they actually read some and listen to others, it's common to simply say **read**.

Of course, if they are text books or school books, you can also use the verb **studied**.